# Clang: x86 FPU calling convention

Tags: c++, x86, clang, sse, calling-convention

I need to support dynamic libraries and static linking of object files for 32 bit platforms (x86): Win32, Linux32 and MacOS32. The problem occurs when passing FPU arguments (float and double). By default, they are passed in SSE registers, not the stack. I am not against SSE, but I need the arguments and the result to be passed standardly - through the stack and the FPU.

[I tried (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/zI5aRL) setting the **-mno-sse** option, and this produces the desired result. But I would not want to completely abandon SSE, I would sometimes like to use intrinsics and/or use MMX/SSE optimizations.

```cpp
__attribute__((stdcall))
long double test(int* num, float f, double d) 
{
    *num = sizeof(long double);
    return f * d;
}
```

```
/*-target i386-windows-gnu -c -O3*/
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        and     esp, -8
        sub     esp, 8
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [ebp + 12] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mov     eax, dword ptr [ebp + 8]
        cvtss2sd        xmm0, xmm0
        mov     dword ptr [eax], 12
        mulsd   xmm0, qword ptr [ebp + 16]
        movsd   qword ptr [esp], xmm0
        fld     qword ptr [esp]
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     16
```

```
/*-target i386-windows-gnu -mno-sse -c -O3*/
        mov     eax, dword ptr [esp + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [eax], 12
        fld     dword ptr [esp + 8]
        fmul    qword ptr [esp + 12]
        ret     16
```

Comment: So your library is written in assembly but you want the lib to be standard across multiple platforms?

Comment: How floats are passed is specified in the platform ABI. It is standard to use FP registers (which are shared with SSE). Why do you think it's non-standard?

Comment: @Nina: This is compiler output, not hand-written asm.  They just (I think) want to compile it in a way that doesn't break the ABI, while still letting them use 80-bit `long double`.

Comment: @rustyx: Because 32-bit calling conventions (other than `vectorcall`) are old and bad, and *don't* do that.  As you can see from the OP's code, FP args are received on the callstack (like integer args), not in x87 stack registers.  One of the advantage of x86-64 is that we got to throw out legacy cruft and design a modern calling convention with SSE2 baked in.  32-bit conventions don't have that.

Answer (score 4):

### Both versions of your function *are* using the same calling convention

> By default, they are passed in SSE registers, not the stack.

That's not what your asm output shows, and not what happens.  Notice that **your first function loads its dword `float` arg from the stack into xmm0, then using `mulsd` with the qword `double` arg also from the stack.**  `movss xmm0, dword ptr [ebp + 12]` is a load that destroys the old contents of XMM0; XMM0 is not an input to this function.

Then, to return the retval in x87 `st0` as per the crusty old 32-bit calling convention you're using, it uses a `movsd` store to the stack and an `fld` x87 load.

The `*` operator promotions the `float` to `double` to match the other operand, resulting in a `double` multiply, not `long double`.  Promotion from `double` to `long double` doesn't happen until that temporary `double` result is returned.

**It looks like clang defaults to what gcc would call `-mfpmath=sse` if available**.  This is normally good, except for small functions where the x87 return value calling convention gets in the way.  (Also note that x87 has "free" promotion from float and double to long double, as part of how `fld dword` and `qword` work.)  Clang isn't checking to see how much overhead it's going to cost to use SSE math in a small function; here it would obviously have been more efficiently to use x87 for one multiply.

**But anyway, `-mno-sse` is not changing the ABI; read your asm more carefully.**  If it was, the generated asm would suck less!

---

On Windows, if you're stuck making 32-bit code at all, `vectorcall` should be a better way to pass/return FP vars when possible: it can use XMM registers to pass/return.  Obviously any ABIs that are set in stone (like for existing libraries) need to be declared correctly so the compiler calls them / receives return values from them correctly.

**What you currently have *is* `stdcall` with FP args on the stack and returned in `st0`.**

---

BTW, a lot of the code in your first function is from clang aligning the stack to spill/reload the temporary `double`; the Windows ABI only guarantees 4-byte stack alignment.  This is amount of work to avoid the risk of a cache-line split is almost certainly not worth it.  Especially when it could have just destroyed its `double d` stack arg as scratch space, and hoped the caller had aligned that.  Optimization is enabled, it's just setting up a frame pointer for it can `and esp` without losing the old ESP.

---

#### You could use `return f * (long double)d;`

That compiles to identical asm to the `-mno-sse` version.  https://godbolt.org/z/LK0s_5

SSE2 doesn't support 80-bit x87 types, so clang is forced to use `fmul`.  It ends up not messing around at all with SSE, and then the result is where it needs it for a return value.

Comment: I need **exactly the old 32-bit calling convention** when the result is returned to st(0) and float/double/long double are passed through the stack. I also want to influence the SSE instructions inside the function, but the calling convention should not know anything about SSE.

Comment: @Listener: this is what you already have, as my answer explains.  Both versions of your function use an identical calling convention.

Comment: Oh my God. You're right. I apologize. Maybe then you can tell me, can I use SSE intrinsics with -mno-sse mode?

Comment: @Listener: no, clang and gcc intrinsics don't override the target arch settings, unlike MSVC and ICC.  You can only use intrinsics for extensions you've enabled.  You could get a similar effect by using `-mfpmath=387` (and optionally ` -march=native or at least `-msse2`)  and using intrinsics, though.  GCC/clang will maybe still auto-vectorize with SSE or AVX, but use x87 for scalar math.

Comment: -mfpmath=387 not supported. error: the '387' unit is not supported with this instruction set

Comment: @Listener: That's weird; I assumed it would mean the same thing for clang as for gcc.  IDK, maybe you need `-march=` something.  I've never needed to get clang to make 32-bit code at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201467/discussion-between-listener-and-peter-cordes).